# Palindrome number check

Tags: palindrome

The problem is to find out if the number is a palindrome. However, the function always returns False. where am I going wrong?

class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        int_list = list(str(x))
        n = len (int_list)

```
    #arr1 = 
    #if (n%2==0):
    #print (int (n/2))

    for i in range(int(n/2)):
        temp1 = (int_list[i])
        temp2 = x%10

        print (temp1)
        print (temp2)

        if temp1==temp2:
            x = x/10
            continue

        else:
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

It always says false because the line, "x = x/10" doesn't return an integer. It returns a decimal. Import the math library with the line "import math". Then replace "x = x/10" with "x = floor(x/10)"

```
#arr1 = 
#if (n%2==0):
#print (int (n/2))
import math
for i in range(int(n/2)):
    temp1 = (int_list[i])
    temp2 = x%10

    print (temp1)
    print (temp2)

    if temp1==temp2:
        x = floor(x/10)
        continue

    else:
        return False

return True
```